# How to set up "Next 10" and "Prev 10" in Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I am trying to step through a large set of Clients using Kaminari.
Thus far I just do this in index.html.erb:

```
<%= paginate @clients, :outer_window => 3 %>
```

which results in:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 588 589 590 Next Last
```

where "Next" just advances to the next one.

I would like to get something like this (roughly)

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 15 25 35 ...
```

so that the user can step through faster than one at a time. I see "Kaminari themes" in the documentation, but couldn't work out how to use it. Thanks...